# AlertDialog.Builder Below 19

Tags: android

How to make this alert to appear on apis below 19? Thanks.

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recover_password_dialog, null);
Button btnSend = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnRecuperar);
final EditText emailRecover = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.emailRecover);
mBuilder.setView(mView);
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

this is bugging my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd.

I had a function to present that dialog. working 100% on api 21 but not on 1.

What I did was delete the function and make OnClickListener on the EditText.

and on the code change this.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = login.this.getLayoutInflater();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you using

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Try change it to

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: I mean. this is working fine on api 21. but on 19 lower doenst show the alert.

Comment: Do you have any error when it hapens? Can you show logcat?

Comment: Nope. On  21 works 100% on 19 doenst show the dialog.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is differents between android.app.AlertDialog and android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog. First one available since API 1 and second one has added in Version 23.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be implementing this import for the AlertDialog class

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Let me know if that helped